# Group string characters into a given length

Tags: java, arrays

I have written a simple code that groups a certain string into N length then print it out to the console where the group of characters are divided by "|" character. Is there a simpler way to do this? By the way, this is my code.

```
String d = "stackoverflow.com";
char[] x = d.toCharArray();
StringBuilder ad = new StringBuilder();
int r = 0;
int f = 6;
/*
f = 1; 2 characters by group
f = 2; 3 characters by group
...
f = n; (n+1) characters by group
*/
for (char a : x) {
    if (r == f) {
        ad.append(a);
        System.out.print(ad+"|");
        ad.delete(0, 1);
    } else {
        ad.append(a);
        r++;
    } 
}
```

Its output will be (f = 6)

```
stackov|tackove|ackover|ckoverf|koverfl|overflo|verflow|erflow.|rflow.c|flow.co|low.com|
```

Comment: Just to check - do you intend this to print out blocks of 7 characters for `f = 6`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you wrap `System.out` in a [`PrintWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html), you can use the overload of `PrintWriter.write` which prints a portion of the string:

```
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out, true);
for (int i = 0; i <= d.length() - f; ++i) {
  pw.write(d, i, f);
  pw.print('|');
}
```

Comment: you could use auto flush thx to new PrintWriter(System.out, true) and use pw.print('|') instead

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick. I still have to put `pw.flush()` though. Anyway, I going to use it as a part of search mechanism, comparing that code's output to different strings.